# How to provoke simulataneous access to shared resource?

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking

I am creating an component which performs sequential processing on inputs. As it will be hosted in several different processes, I need it to be thread safe. At first, I intentionally left out thread safety from the code. Now it is time to introduce that.

First, I wanted to provoke an error to start with, but was not able to. Here is a simplified version of the code for the processing engine:

```
public Document DoOrchestration(Document input)
{
    Document output = new Document();

    foreach (var orchestrationStep in m_OrchestrationSteps)
    {
        var processor = GetProcessor(orchestrationStep).Clone();

        output = processor.Process(input);

        input = output;
    }

    return output;
}
```

The processors can be developed by other people in my organisation, and that can include some complex initialization. They may also be thread unsafe, so I use the Prototype Pattern to get unique instances of the to avoid threading issues in those.

To test this function I used the following code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20000; i++)
{
    Thread t = new Thread(() => TestOrchestration(i));
    t.Start();
}

void TestOrchestration(int number)
{
    Document doc = new Document(string.Format("Test {0}", number));
    doc = DoOrchestration(doc);
    if (doc.ToString().Substring(0,35) != strExpectedResult)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", doc.ToString();
    }
}
```

I expected that some of the threads would collide with another and mix up their results, but to my surprise that did not happen.

There is probably a easy and logical explanation to this, but it eludes me. Or is it just that the code is too simple to result in two threads fiddling with the input/output variables at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [CHESS](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/chess/).

> CHESS is a tool for finding and reproducing Heisenbugs in concurrent
>   programs. CHESS repeatedly runs a concurrent test ensuring that every
>   run takes a different interleaving. If an interleaving results in an
>   error, CHESS can reproduce the interleaving for improved debugging.
>   CHESS is available for both managed and native programs.

Comment: I have heard of CHESS, but I tried to go the easy route. Instead of learning how to apply CHESS, I tried to make an, perhaps oversimplistic, test application myself. But in the long run, may CHESS is worth the investment in time...

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that due to the simplicity of your test function, your threads do not even get the time to spawn in a large quantity before the previous one is done with it's work. Consider using a [barrier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.barrier.aspx) to allow all threads to spawn before you start the computational step. Also, you will want to consider increasing the complexity of your test case, for instance by performing several of the same operation in the same loop (starting a thread is expensive, and allows other cores to complete their work before you even get around to the resource contention.

Generally, resource contention can be provoked by having rapid access to the same resource over a longer period of time, your test case does not seem to allow for this. As an aside, I would strongly recommend that you design for thread safety in mind, instead of introducing this later. When working with the code you have a better understanding of resource access patterns than you will have when analyzing the code at a later stage.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely correct. I should have designed for thread safety in the first place. However, in this case my intention is to create an Object Pool and have the guard condition in the resource manager for the pool instead of in the actual orchestration engine. In that way I can have several orchestrations engines running at the same time instead of having blocking calls to one instance.

Answer (score 0):

I think your test function is almost complete before next thread starts. You can make all the threads wait on an ManualResetEventSlim before invoking the orchestration function and then set the ManualResetEventSlim

That way all your threads will infact try to invoke orchestration at the same time.


Also possibly you would not need 20,000 threads to simulate this behavior if all threads male orchestracion call at almost the same time

```
ManualResetEventSlim manualEvent = new ManualResetEventSlim (false);

for (int i = 0; i < 20000; i++)
{
    Thread t = new Thread(() => TestOrchestration(i));
    t.Start();
}
manualEvent.Set();

void TestOrchestration(int number)
{
    manualEvent.Wait();
    Document doc = new Document(string.Format("Test {0}", number));
    doc = DoOrchestration(doc);
    if (doc.ToString().Substring(0,35) != strExpectedResult)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", doc.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that was a reason for not seeing any concurrency problems to start with. However, when signaling the AutoresetEvent, that only let one thread through at a time. Which I think is by design. So I did the same thing in a simpler (more naive) way, by having all threads waiting for a bool value and setting that after all threads were spawned. The interesting result of this was that in the line where I created the new document on which to perform the orchestration, the parametet Number collided between threads. However, the actual orchestration seemed to work.

Comment: @jonas-samuelsson Not sure why would let only one thread at a time?

Comment: @JonasSamuelsson I should have used ManualResentEvent, AutoResetEvent would be set back to non-signaled state, that was the reason for letting only one thread. I have corrected the answer o use ManualResetEventSlim

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `ManualResetEvent` for simultaneous continuation of any number of awaiting threads.